# C++ Vector Values not correct

Tags: c++, vector, opensg

Im in the middle of creating an application with openSG and C++.

Can anyone tell me, why these lines(174ff):

```
Vec3f snakeDirection = (1,2,3);
std::cout << "direction"<<  snakeDirection<<"\n";
```

prints

```
direction 3,0,0
```

the complete code for my scene can be found here:

http://pastie.org/9420616#20,177

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try getting rid of the `=`. You're probably calling a 1-parameter constructor with "3" (the result of evaluating the parenthesized `,` expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ the expression `(1,2,3)` forces the compiler to interpret the commas inside the parentheses as the *sequential-evaluation operator*. 
The sequential-evaluation operator is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand as `void` and discards the result, it then evaluates the second operand and returns its value and type. Therefore, the expression `(1,2,3)` is going to be evaluated in the following way:

1. First `1` is evaluated and discarded, then `(2,3)` is evaluated and the result `(2,3)` is returned.
2. First `2` is evaluated and discarded, then `3` is evaluated and the result `3` is returned.

Consequently, the evaluation of the expression `(1,2,3)` will return `3`.

Thus, stating:

```
Vec3f snakeDirection = (1,2,3);
```

is the same as stating:

```
Vec3f snakeDirection = 3;
```

What you've probably intended to write is either:

```
Vec3f snakeDirection = Vec3f(1, 2, 3);
```

or

```
Vec3f snakeDirection(1, 2, 3);
```

or

```
Vec3f snakeDirection{1, 2, 3};
```

or

```
Vec3f snakeDirection = {1, 2, 3};
```